# React JS : Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, unexpected-token

I am new to ReactJS. This is my first React Program. Actually, it's a dynamic page, I am working it with API that's working fine but I want to search in dynamically. I have tried with some tutorials but it shows some errors. Kindly fix the issue. My code is given below:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'; 
import './App.css'; 

function About() {

    state ={
      search : ""
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchItems();
    }, []);

    const [set, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      'http://www.ongccreditsociety.com/api/circular.php'
      );

    const set = await data.json();
    console.log(set); 
    setItems(set);
    };

    onchange = e => {
      this.setState({ search : e.target.value});
    }

    render(){ 
      const {search} = this.state;
      const filter =  set.filter( country =>{
        return country.Description.toLowercase().indexOf(search.toLowercase() ) != -1
      })

    return ( 
      <div className="items">
        <div className="col">
          <input label="search" icon="search" onChange={this.onchange} /> 
        </div>
        {filter.map(item => (
          <p>{item.Description}</p> 
        ))} 
      </div>  
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

Error is  :

```
      Failed to compile
      ./src/about.js
      Line 30:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

      28 |       }
      29 | 
      30 |       render(){ 
         |               ^
      31 |         const {search} = this.state;
      32 |         const filter =  set.filter( country =>{
      33 |           return country.Description.toLowercase().indexOf(search.toLowercase() ) != -1
    This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Comment: use render method inside a class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your react component is a function component. You don't need the render method inside the function component. That function itself is the render function.

This will work

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function About() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const [set, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      "http://www.ongccreditsociety.com/api/circular.php"
    );

    const set = await data.json();
    console.log(set);
    setItems(set);
  };

  const onchange = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const filter = set.filter(country => {
    return (
      country.Description.toLowercase().indexOf(search.toLowercase()) != -1
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="items">
      <div className="col">
        <input label="search" icon="search" onChange={onchange} />
      </div>
      {filter.map(item => (
        <p>{item.Description}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Comment: `this.setState({ search: e.target.value });`? how?

Comment: It is valid. Every javscript function also has `this` attached to it. It will not work because there is no setState method attached to `this`. So will throw an exception at runtime. 

I did correct that error.

Comment: I referred valid as you wrote `state = { search: "" };` in a function.

Comment: Yes. That is also valid javascript. It will create a variable named `state` in the global scope (actually the module scope or the scope just outside this function).

Comment: I know it's confusing because the same syntax is used to initialize class variables now. Would love to know why you think it's invalid.

Comment: What?`function hello() { myWorld = { x: 5}; }`, please show me an example of accessing `this.myWorld`. (as myWorld not pre defined).

Comment: this.myWorld does not exist. But both the statements are valid javascript. They will not throw an exception until you access it. I am not saying it's the right code. All i am saying is it's "valid" javascript code. In your code above, `myWorld` will get defined as a global variable. this.myWorld will throw an exception because there is no property called `myWorld` on `this` attached to the `hello` function.

Comment: If "valid" is without compile errors, you are right. Just to note that your code is incorrect, `this.onChange`, `this.setState`, `this.state` all those will get runtime errors (as your code is written for now).

Comment: I had removed all references to `this.state`. Have changed `this.onchange` to `onchange`. Thanks!

Comment: still, it's incorrect, `onchange` will refer to `window.onchange` function no to `this.onchange`

Comment: It's not the right way, but it will work :). onchange is definitely defined on global scope but when you access it, the javascript engine will run up the prototype chain to find it and will finally find it on `global.onchange` (window.onchange in the browser).

Comment: I have made onchange a local variable because that's how all idiomatic JS is written nowadays.

Comment: I think that anyway this answer is correct: the OP's code gave an error because it mixed the syntax of class components with the syntax of function components. Removing the `render` function and putting everything that needs to be rendered in the `return` of the function will fix the issue.

Comment: TypeError: country.Description.toLowercase is not a function

Comment: It's working now..I change the below one:    return country.Description.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toString().toLowerCase())!= -1

Answer (score 2):

Many issue's in your code,

1. You have combined class component and functional component.
2. `set` is a reserved word, don't use variable with name `set`.
3. `toLowercase()` is a typo, it should be `toLowerCase()`.
4. We don't have access to `this` in functional component.
5. Your search `input` should be [`controlled`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

So you final code should look like this,

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'; 

const About = () => {
    const [item, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchItems();
    }, []);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('http://www.ongccreditsociety.com/api/circular.php');
      const dataSet = await data.json();
      setItems(dataSet);
    };

    onchange = e => {
      setSearch(e.target.value);
    }

    return ( 
      <div className="items">
        <div className="col">
          <input label="search" icon="search" onChange={onchange} value={search}/> 
        </div>
        {search !=="" ? 
          item.filter(item => item.Description.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())).map(item => ( <p key={item.SNo}>{item.Description}</p>)) 
          :
          item.map(item => (<p key={item.SNo}>{item.Description}</p>))
        } 
      </div>  
    );
}

export default About;
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xuu5rf)